# reading data file on any network device from java applet?

Tags: security, signed, applet

how can java applets read data file from any device which is in same network with client computer

is it possible with signed applets or with any security policy ?

Comment: You might want to be careful that you don't open up a vulnerability. Perhaps that is wishful thinking - most people don't seem to give a toss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/applet/readFileApplet.shtml

here i found a sample application exactly what i want thanks for all answers
so there is no need to sign applet because they can read data where they are originated from :)

Answer (score 0):

Signed applets [do not have the security restrictions that are imposed on unsigned applets and can run outside the security sandbox.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836007/java-applet-network-connection) is similar, although there aren't many answers.